# Serializing class implementing ICollection

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a collection class implementing `ICollection<T>` with a few custom attributes thrown in for completeness..

In this simplistic sample, its a simple Request/Results pattern with the request itself being passed back as an attribute of the results class.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyRequest
{
    public int SearchID { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class MyResults : ICollection<MyElement>
{
    public MyRequest RequestDetails { get; set; }
    private ICollection<MyElement> _list = new List<MyElement>();

    /* ICollection interface methods removed */
}

[Serializable]
public class MyElement
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the sample program to instantiate and then output a serialized string.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyResults m = new MyResults();
        m.RequestDetails = new MyRequest() { SearchID = 1 };

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            m.Add(new MyElement { ID = i });
        }

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(m.GetType());
        using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, m);
            xmlStream.Position = 0;
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the output is not including the `MyRequest` details...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfMyElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <MyElement>
        <ID>1</ID>
    </MyElement>
    <MyElement>
        <ID>2</ID>
    </MyElement>
    <MyElement>
        <ID>3</ID>
    </MyElement>
    <MyElement>
        <ID>4</ID>
    </MyElement>
    <MyElement>
        <ID>5</ID>
    </MyElement>
</ArrayOfMyElement>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` always ignores extra properties when serializing a collection; the only way to do it, as far as I know, is not to implement `ICollection<MyElement>` on your `MyResults` class, and instead expose the collection as a property:

```
public class MyResults
{
    public MyRequest RequestDetails { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MyElement> Items { get; set; }
}
```

(the `Serializable` attribute isn't needed for XML serialization)

Comment: Also had to change `ICollection<>` to `List<>` as XmlSerialization does not support interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Just change **ICollection** to **Collection** because XmlSerialization does not support Generic Interfaces:

```cs
public class MyResults
{
    public MyResults()
    {
        this.Items= new Collection<MyElement>();
    }
    public MyRequest RequestDetails { get; set; }
    public Collection<MyElement> Items { get; set; }
}
```