# "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[StudentsManagementSystem.Entity.CreateStudentEntity]

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am new to .NET and the MVC architecture. I am working on a mini project to create API for students information processing. However, I encountered the following error while attempting to create a collection of new students using curl:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":[REDACTED],"errors":{"$":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[StudentsManagementSystem.Entity.CreateStudentEntity]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."]}}
```

Here's the Controller class that should handle the request:

```
namespace StudentsManagementSystem.StudentController{
[ApiController]
[Route("api/student/Collections")]
public class StudentCollectionController: ControllerBase
{
    private IStudentRepository _students;
    private IMapper _mapper;
    public StudentCollectionController(IMapper mapper, IStudentRepository student)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _students = student;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>> CreateStudentCollection(IEnumerable<CreateStudentEntity> newStudents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUGG");
        if (newStudents.Count<CreateStudentEntity>()< 1) return BadRequest();
        var map = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Student>>(newStudents);
        foreach(var student in map)
        {
            _students.AddStudent(student);
        }
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The `CreateStudentEntity` Class:

```
namespace StudentsManagementSystem.Entity{
public class CreateStudentEntity
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public string MatricNo { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
    public int YOA { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Results { get; set; } = new List<Course>();
}
```

`Student` Entity class:

```
namespace StudentsManagementSystem.Entity{
public class Student
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string MatricNo { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
    public int YOA { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Results { get; set; } = new List<Course>();


}
```

The `curl` request:

`curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/student/collections -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{{}}"`

Note:`DEBUGG` was not written on the console.

Kindly help a n00b :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serializing class implementing ICollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589545/serializing-class-implementing-icollection)

Comment: It looks like you're passing an empty object in cURL with `"{{}}"` but that's not valid json (`{}` is a valid empty object).  You'll need to create a json array of `CreateStudentEntity` objects. The array should contain all properties in the model. It'll start something like: `'[{"MatricNo": "123", ....}]'` but I'll leave you to complete the rest...

Comment: You could try using an empty array or an array with an empty object but it might not bind to the model: `'[{}]'`

Comment: @haldo Thanks, the square bracket works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you're sending in the cURL request - `{{}}` - isn't valid JSON and doesn't represent an array.  Arrays in JSON are represented by square brackets `[]` and objects by curly brackets `{}`.

So, if you want to pass an empty array to the controller you'd use `[]`.

If you want to pass an array containing an empty object it would be `[{}]`, eg:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/student/collections -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "[{}]"
```

To pass `CreateStudentEntity` objects in the array you'd need to include the properties, eg:

```
[{"MatricNo": "ABC123", "StudentId": 123, ...}, {object2...}, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you still haven't created the mapping in the AutoMapper settings to transform an object of type "CreateStudentEntity" into an object of type "Student".

Check the [AutoMapper Documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html)

In your case it would be something like:

```
public class StudentProfile : Profile
{
     public StudentProfile()
     {
        CreateMap<Student, CreateStudentEntity>()
         .ReverseMap();
     }
}
```

This is the least code you will need.